# Ownership of default selection model of QListView

Tags: c++, qt, model

The [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) states that `setModel` will create and set a new selection model, replacing any model that was previously set with `setSelectionModel()`. However, the old selection model will not be deleted as it may be shared between several views. They recommend to delete the old selection model if it is no longer required. Does this apply to the default selection model too?

Comment: Good question, but it is easy to get an answer in Qt sources ;)

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I appreciate finding an answer here after short googling rather than digging into Qt sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to manually delete default selection model. Default selection model is created by a view, and it uses view as a parent. So it will be deleted accordinally to object ownership (automatically, if you don't change a parent of selection model).

You may look at qt sources:

```
void QAbstractItemView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)
{
    //...
    QItemSelectionModel *selection_model = new QItemSelectionModel(d->model, this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please  give some "proof". E.g. e reference or sth like that

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r you may open `qabstractitemview.cpp` file. Code is better proof, even it's not documented ;)

Comment: @DmitrySazonov but I dont have sources at my disposal. I am linking against qt, so I have only libs and shared libs on my machine. And since when can you download qt sources? I though it is closed-source